# How to return html in d3 text function?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to be able to return html from the text function like this:

```
textEnter.append("tspan")
          .attr("x", 0)
          .text(function(d,i) {
             return 'some text' + '<br/>' + d.someProp;
           })
```

Tried to use `&lt;br&gt;`, but didnot work. How do I achieve this?

Comment: I don't know about d3, but I noticed you're setting the text as html code. Can't you do something like `.html` or `.innerHTML` instead of `.text()` ?

Answer (score 22):

**EDITED ANSWER**

Just noticed that you're working with a tspan here. Unfortunately you can't insert line breaks into svg text elements. Multiline text with SVG requires breaking up the text yourself and then laying it out by setting the `dy` attribute. D3 makes the laying out process pretty straight forward, but it still takes extra work.

More info in the intro paragraph here: http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html

**OLD ANSWER (applies if using html elements, not svg)**

D3 has a separate method for this: the `html()` method, which works just like `text()` but unescaped. [More info here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-html). So, easily enough, you just need:

```
textEnter.append("tspan")
      .attr("x", 0)
      .html(function(d,i) {
         return 'some text' + '<br/>' + d.someProp;
       })
```