# Line break in D3.js

Tags: svg, d3.js

```
d3.select('svg g.chart #countryLabel')
  .html(d.Patient_id+"<br/>"+descriptions[xAxis]+':'+d[xAxis]+"<br/>"+
        descriptions[Axis]+':'+d[yAxis])
  .transition()
  .style('opacity', 1);
```

I can't get the line break into the chart. What should I do now?

Comment: Do you want to add breaks or remove the breaks?

Comment: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

Comment: I want to add line breaks

Comment: The example that Lars links to shows how to manually wrap text over multiple lines. Check the `wrap` function in there. Your approach of nesting HTML into the SVG may also work, but we'll need some more context to be able to help you. Do you have a small example somewhere of your chart (data, js and html) that we can look at?

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657319/how-to-return-html-in-d3-text-function, which says the `html()` is only useful when you're outputting **only** HTML, not for nesting HTML inside of SVG.

Comment: Finally, see this question for a successful attempt of embedding HTML into SVG. That approach leans on the `foreignObject` tag in SVG, which seems less widely supported.