# How to make my bubble label can be wrapped not overflow the circle

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

The is how I decorated my circle text,

I copied it from somewhere.

But it still seems overflow the circle and don't  wrapped automatically.

How to make my label text in the circle can be wrapped

for example if `This is stackoverflow`
It should be wrapped as following (if it it overflowed in the circle )

```
This is
stackoverflow
```

### Here's my javascript snippet

```
.select('text')
          .attr("dy", ".3em")
          .style("text-anchor", "middle")
          .style("font-size", function(d) {
            var len = d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3).length;
            var size = d.r/3;
            size *= 10 / len;
            size += 1;
            return Math.round(size)+'px';
          })
          .text(function(d) {
            var text = d.className.substring(0, d.r / 3);
            return text;
          });
```

[image]

Comment: This might help http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7555321

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return html in d3 text function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657319/how-to-return-html-in-d3-text-function)