# html label inside d3 element

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, hover

I have written the following code (it's a toy example, [here](https://jsfiddle.net/eduaj4u8/1) on jsfiddle) to show a label when hovering a shape:

```
var lbl;
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
      .attr("width", 200)
      .attr("height", 200);
        svg.append("rect")
      .attr("x", 50)
      .attr("y", 0)
          .attr("width",50)
      .attr("height",50)
          .attr("label","first line"+"<br/>"+"second line")
      .style("fill", "yellow")  
          .on("mouseover",function() {
               var th=d3.select(this);
               lbl=svg.append("text")
                   .attr("x", th.attr("x")*1+th.attr("width")/2)
                   .attr("y", th.attr("y")*1+th.attr("height")/2)
                   .attr("dy", "0.5em")
                   .style("text-anchor", "middle")
                   .style("visibility", "visible")
               .attr("pointer-events", "none")
                   .text(th.attr("label"));
        })
          .on("mouseout",function(){
             lbl.remove();
            });
```

How can I render the label in html format?

Comment: Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657319/how-to-return-html-in-d3-text-function. If you change your .text(th.attr("label")); to .html(th.attr("label")); it will recognize the <br/> but in order to new line it, you must either append 2 text or use the tspan element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a div and give css `position:absolute`
so that you can now position it w.r.t. the top and left calculated.

Also set the text within the div like `.html("your html<br> text")`

```
var th=d3.select(this);
               lbl=d3.select("#chart").append("div")
                .attr("class", "tooltip")
                   .style("left", (th.attr("x")*1+th.attr("width")/2) + "px")
                   .style("top", (th.attr("y")*1+th.attr("height")/2) + "px")
                   .html(th.attr("label"));
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/dqzdcw9y/)